# Java multi-thread creation in a static method

Tags: java, multithreading, static-methods

I'm totally new to Java (but I have some knowledge on C++) and I can't find an answer on the existing topics.

I have a public class containing a static method. This one creates a number of Threads, each one instantiating an instance of this class, each instance has a blocking treatment.

I tried adding a Runnable as a field of this class, but I'm a little bit confused about how to properly do it...

```
public class MyClass extends java.awt.Frame {
    String myString1;
    String myString2;
    String myString3;
    private ActionListener aL;
    private volatile boolean boolRunning;

    public Runnable r = new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            MyClass q = new MyClass(MyClass.this);
            synchronized (this) {
                MyClass.this.notify();
            }
        }
    }

    private MyClass(String toParse){
        String[] parsed = toParse.split(":");
        this.myString1 = parsed[0];
        this.myString2 = parsed[1];
        this.myString3 = parsed[2];
        instantiateFrame();
    }

    public void instantiateFrame(){
        this.setBounds(...);
        this.setLayout(...);
        Button btn = new Button("Submit");
        [...]
        this.aListener = new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                /************************/
                /* Treatment hear       */
                /* Increment static Var */
                /************************/
                synchronized (MyClass.this){
                    boolRunning = true;
                    MyClass.this.notify();
                }
                MyClass.this.dispose();
            }
        };
        btn.addActionListener(aL);
        this.add(btn);
        this.setVisible(true);
        /* Wait for btn clicked */
        /* Blocking method */
        synchronized(this) {
            try {
                this.wait();
                boolRunning = true;
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }

    public static int startThreads(String[] toParseTable){
        Thread[] t = new Thread[toParseTable.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < toParseTable.length; i++) {
            t[i] = new Thread(MyClass.r);       // Not compiling : Non static variable "r" cannot be referenced from a static context
            t[i].start();
        }
        /* Wait for all Threads */
        for (Thread th : t) {
            try {
                th.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
        return MyClass.someStaticVar;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] someStrings = {"...:...:...",
                                "...:...:...",
                                "...:...:..."};
        try {
            System.out.println(MyClass.startThreads(someStrings));
        } catch (CustomThrownException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question, specifically? Take a look at [ask]

Comment: there are quite some issues in your code. I'd advise to learn more about Java before you make an attempt at multithreading.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access an instance variable (that is a variable belonging to an object) in a method that does not belong to an instance object but to the class. `static` functions and variables are class global, but cannot access variables from instances because there is no implicit `this`.

```
class Foo {
  private int value = 2;
  private static int woz = 6;

  public void foo() {
    System.out.println(value); // ok, access instance variable in instance method with implicit this object
    System.out.println(woz); // ok, access 'class global' variable
  }


  public static void bar() { // is a 'class' method, not an instance method
     System.out.println(value); // can't because there is no 'this' object here
     System.out.println(woz); // ok, access 'class global' variable
 }
```

Comment: I know about static methods, but I can't see how to do it an other way !

Comment: In my experience it is never necessary to use static variables, non other than when used in singletons or constants.